# pcntl-fork equivalent with php-fpm

Tags: php, fpm, pcntl

I have recently migrated one of my php applications from hostgator to AWS using the Apache AMI.

The PHP is running with the server API as FMP/FastCGI, my code is currently built for CGI/FastCGI.

With the change I lost my pcntl_fork() function.

I used the pcntl_fork to start a long running process from a browser interface and be able to continue to use the browser.

I have no experience working with FPM API or its differences to the CGI.

With that said my question is where is the documentation on working with the FPM (if I am thinking this right)

How would I accomplish this with my current setup?

Or I could be completely missing the mark altogether, any direction would be very appreciated.

basic premise of what used to work,  now getting call to undefined function pcntl_fork

```
loop() {
 $pid = pcntl_fork()
 if($pid === 0) {
   do new process
 } else if($pid === -1) {
   process error
 } else {
  $pidAry[] = $pid
  continue loop
 }
}
```

Comment: It's not that you can't fork in FPM, but that you seem to be using a build that doesn't have it properly enabled. That said, forking web worker processes is kind of a bad idea, even worse if you're leaving them as orphaned "background tasks". You're one error/exploit away from a de-facto DoS of zombie processes eating resources and taking your system down. I would strongly suggest moving to a queue/worker system where background tasks are submitted to a queue and handled by a set number of workers. Eg: RabbitMQ and supervisord to manage the workers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Sammitch, I do think your process would be a better way to do it.  It will be more secure, more controllable and trackable.  At the most basic, I could throw the needed process in a queue table and then poll it at an interval and process what is pending.  Again thanks for getting me out of the forest.